# Marketing Cloud_ImportFile Activity error

Tags: marketing-cloud, automationstudio, data-import

We're trying to import a csv fial in a file-drop-to-our-FTP scenario and subsequent import file activity. We're keep getting this error sent by Marketing Cloud upon executing the automation: Results:

```
Inserted: 0
Updated: 0
```

ValidationErrors:

```
Field Not Found: 1
Required Field: 530
```

Could a reason for this be that all the fields in the target data extension were set as "Text", and in our source csv files we have a lot fields formatted in Excel as "number", "decimal" and "postal code", or this does not affect Marketing Cloud?

Comment: looks like your csv is missing some required fields, check your csv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you exported from Excel to csv, everything became plain text. So no, those formatted fields would have nothing to do with these errors.

Your csv file apparently contains 1 row where 1 one of its columns has data that does not have a corresponding column in your DE.

Your csv file apparently also contains 530 rows where 1 of their columns corresponds to a column in your DE where the "nullable" checkbox is not checked, or it is set as a primary key.

When you use the "Import Into Data Extension" wizard, remember to give special attention to Step 2: "Configure Mapping." You have a choice of 3 mapping modes for your convenience. Use the 1 where the relationships seem to make the most sense to you and, if all else fails, just use "Map Manually."

Comment: Tnx, I will check it out based on your comments.

Answer (score 1):

I also have the same issue but I resolved it by giving the file mapping "Map by Ordinal  and checked Import file had column headers" instead of Map Manually.. then all records are imported